# Noise from gearbox since new brake pads and discs

Tags: brakes, noise, vauxhall, astra

I have a 2006 Vauxhall Astra automatic which was making a wearing sound around left front wheel. I had both front brake pads plus discs replaced. Now when my car is in park with the engine running, I press the brake pedal on & off and there is now a clicking noise which seems to be coming from the gear box area......any ideas please?

Comment: The sound is more than likely not coming from the gearbox, it might just sound like it is, as for the noise it could be a variety of things from your piston sticking to trapped air in your system.

if you get someone to press the brakes whilst you walk around the car you can probably get more of an idea as to where the noise is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

In most cars with automatic transmission, if not all, it is normal to hear a "clicking" sound from underneath the gear selector.

Pressing the brake pedal activates the brake switch, which disengages the park lock solenoid to allow the selector to move out of P. The "click" sound is emitted when the parking lock is released.

Comment: This seems really odd.  Wouldn't she have to press the brake in P in order to put it into D anyway?

Comment: @DucatiKiller yes, she was complaining of a noise when she's in park. I'm guessing that the noise is the parking lock getting disengaged/engaged

Comment: Yes, I re-read it and now understand.